# Can't ping interfaces from other subnets

Tags: networking, server

I got an Ubuntu server in a VM which has three interfaces.

- 192.168.70.153 ens160
- 192.168.60.30 ens224
- 192.168.10.219 ens192

My PfSense router has allowed all to all in all subnet's rules.

When I try to ping across subnet's it fails, e.g. 192.168.10.69 to 192.168.70.153. I can ping docker containers inside that VM what is on the vlan 70 subnet.

I know I can ping across subnets as I can ping other VM's with multiple interfaces.

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.70.1 dev ens160
default via 192.168.60.1 dev ens224 metric 2
default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens192 metric 3
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio proto kernel scope link src 172.30.32.1 linkdown
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.219
192.168.60.0/24 dev ens224 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.30
192.168.70.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.70.153
```

[image: Rules of VLAN70]

[image: Rules of VLAN10]

Resolution:

```
$ echo 13 <name> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
$ ip route add default via <gateway> table <name>
$ ip rule add from <Interface ip> lookup <name>
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `ip route`? You probably need to add the routes to access those subnets. `ping -v` could provide more info. I'm not familiar with your notation, could you use CIDR Subnet Mask Notation?

Comment: `default via 192.168.70.1 dev ens160
default via 192.168.60.1 dev ens224 metric 2
default via 192.168.10.1 dev ens192 metric 3
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.30.32.0/23 dev hassio proto kernel scope link src 172.30.32.1 linkdown
192.168.10.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.219
192.168.60.0/24 dev ens224 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.60.30
192.168.70.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.70.153`

ping -v works due to exiting out of the vlan 10 interface

Comment: This is how you fix it = 
echo 13 <name> >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via <gateway> table <name>
ip rule add from <Interface ip> lookup <name>

Comment: Please add the resolution as an answer to your own question, adding all the relevant information and documentation.